# Screen backlight does not turn on during bootup, but turns on when accessing recovery partition

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, startup, filevault, backlight

I have a late-2011 15" MacBook Pro running Mavericks.  I normally don't reboot my computer and can leave it logged in for days on end.  I decided to reboot my computer and when it was booting, the screen backlight would not turn on, although I could faintly see the login screen where I could type my password.

I tried resetting the SMC, but that didn't do anything.

I also tried resetting the PRAM, but I'm guessing because I have a firmware password and the computer is FileVault-encrypted, instead of actually resetting the PRAM, I have the prompt to type in my firmware password (also really faint since the backlight isn't on).  If I type in my password, it boots into the recovery partition and the display backlight finally turns on. However upon reboot, the backlight will stop working again.

I tried using Disk Utility to check for any permissions/disk errors but didn't find any issues.

I haven't tried logging in with the faint login screen, only because I can't find my mouse cursor to select my account to login.  I've tried rebooting with both the power cable connected and disconnected.

How can I get my screen backlight to turn back on again?

Comment: After clicking around a ton in the dimmed login screen I was able to finally click on my user account and login.  After boot the screen backlight did turn on.  When I tried rebooting, the backlight finally did turn on without any issues.  I also tried a full shutdown and poweron and the backlight still turned on.  I guess the successful login fixed the issue, but perhaps someone has some idea as to the cause?

Comment: Typically the PRAM reset will resolve this odd issue, though in your case you're correct in that your firmware password would prevent that.  If it were to happen again I would boot to the recovery partition, disable the password, reset the PRAM and see if the issue is resolved.  I wish I could give you a definitive answer but in my experience as a technician it's usually felt like an odd software bug that gets reset when the PRAM is reset.

Comment: Just in case anyone else finds this - you can select which account to login using the arrow keys, so you can at least get further than this point. With a torch/flashlight, you should be able to see which account is highlighted. The rest in my case [on an old Mojave Macbook Pro of similar age] was a FileVault issue… solved by disabling FV once I'd realised how to use the torch to get into the OS.

Comment: Just to link these in the sidebar - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458395/macbook-pro-2012-black-screen-after-flat-battery

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The dimmed screen happened during the reboot after turning on file vault. I was able to solve the problem by going into a darkroom. This allowed me to see the cursor and to log in to an account. Once I logged in the back light came on and everything was fine.

I had first tried to solve the problem by zapping the pram. This had no effect.

Comment: I am so surprised that no one agree with this solution! I hit this issue today when updating 10.10.3 and use the same solution it works.

Comment: I had similar - mine wouldn't go away until I disabled FileVault.

Answer (score 2):

If you put some light on back through apple logo you can see the logging screen more clearly!

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences > Displays : Uncheck Automatically adjust brightness
..that's what fixed it for me :)