# MacBook Pro 2012 - black screen after flat battery

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, battery, filevault

After working perfectly whilst never being allowed to run completely flat, booting after a flat battery, even after fully recharging, doesn't switch the backlight on. This means the user cannot see the FileVault password request & consequently the machine appears to not boot. Fans spin at minimum. Eventually if left alone, from this state it will shut itself right down again.

SMC reset, NVRAM etc have no effect.
Booting to Recovery *does* light the screen, but holding  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  in an attempt to re-install from USB doesn't.

<sup>This is a condensation of the initial red herrings & misdirections researched in [MacBook Pro 2012 black screen at boot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458127/macbook-pro-2012-black-screen-at-boot)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually, after realising this was lack of backlight rather than lack of all screen activity, I managed to use a torch [flashlight] to see the screen sufficiently to know to enter the password at the appropriate time.

In my investigation I discovered once you could get through to a working OS, disabling FileVault re-enables the light at initial boot. Re-encrypting then continues to work.

I have yet to test whether allowing the battery to completely flatten will reliably repeat his process, however, I do know for next time…all I need is a torch.

Comment: That's a lovely little tip that may be useful to someone.

Comment: OT: I have Siri on my iPhone speaking in the male UK voice. I once asked it: "Hey Siri, turn on the flashlight." and it responded: "Torch is on." I can use 'torch' interchangeably with flashlight, too. I love these little things Apple thinks of.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have a couple of those models - great machines.

A red light on the power means the battery is below 10% and it's fast charging.

Cycle count is a useful metric, but not an absolute 'ticking clock'. If it's 10 years old with only 2 cycles, it's still going to be knackered.

No chime is a bit of a worry. It *should* boot regardless of the battery's condition. You could try seeing if it will boot if you unplug the battery from the board.

You can get third-party battery replacements on eBay for very little money -- they are of course a bit of a lottery as they are all 'grey'. I have had very good results with ones that claim to be genuine, with Apple writing on them.

You could try taking it to an Apple Store for diagnostics. They sold them til October 2016, so they're 'vintage', but not quite 'obsolete'.

Comment: Ach - it almost had a 'moment' & I might have blown it… After sitting yet more time [another couple of hours] in 'fully off, I checked no hum, it chimed once again on pressing boot, then 3 or 4 minutes later I got the 'thermometer' followed by a 'did you forget your password?' screen. After reading the 3 proposed options I decided to see if pressing the Back button would just ask me again for a password [which I know, of course]. It didn't, it rebooted… to blackscreen. I'm gonna have to test this again after 'some more' charging.

Comment: Meh, I got it to that point again, after which it asked for an admin PW to 'turn off filevault'. After 3 seconds it said, 'Filevault succesfully decrypted, rebooting' … to the same blackscreen. This is getting irritating :\

Comment: I've eventually realised the issue is not what I thought it was, which kind of makes this entire question moot. The issue turns out to be 'no backlight until some point mid-boot process' which I cannot quite tie down yet. Recovery takes a long time to show up, but eventually lights the screen. Opt at boot does not, though you can see the choices using an external lamp. Currently have full access & am disabling FileVault to further test.

Comment: Whole issue eventually 'fixed' by switching off FileVault - not a real solution, but a workaround.

Comment: After eventually figuring out actually what was happening & some conversation in the chat room, I've re-posted this question in condensed form, with an answer, referencing back to here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: *NB* for anyone reading this after the merge - this answer was merged in from the question linked in my OP *after* the prior investigation. Please don't downvote it of not quite seeming to fit. It fit perfectly in it original location, pre-merge.