# Internal MBP monitor turns black after login (but mostly turns back on again)

Tags: display

I am experiencing a strange behavior of my internal display (MacBook Pro 14, 2021) since upgrading to Ventura.

Most of the time the internal monitor turns black after I log in and then immediately turns on again. Sometimes it does not do this at all, but very rarely it turns black and stays black. Also the internal display sometimes turns and stays black, when I connect to the power supply. If it stays black in any of this cases, all I can do to solve this is rebooting. In the settings the screen is still available.

Any ideas what could cause this? Hope it's not hardware related. However, I don't think so, since a reboot always helps and to me it looks more like a software issue.

Comment: Define 'black' for us… Has the image gone, or the backlight? You can shine a torch [flashlight] onto it to see if it's still displaying an image.

Comment: Need to check this next time, but I assume it's the image. So, it's completely off. No image visible even in very light conditions or with a flashlight.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458395/macbook-pro-2012-black-screen-after-flat-battery for a recent experience. I was really surprised just how 'black' black can be with the backlight off.

Comment: So, It just happened again after a while directly after the startup. The screen was completely off, but I could still drag windows there. There was nothing visible at all. Before it happened the Mac stalled when I tried to shut it down. And I got a different screen connected during the day. Not sure, if any of it is connected.