# MacBook Pro 13. OS 12.5.1 - Touch Bar broken, screen brightness on zero, can’t adjust

Tags: macbook-pro, accessibility, touch-bar, remote-control, guided-access

The Touch Bar on my MacBook has been broken for awhile so I have to adjust everything with trackpad. I turned display brightness down all the way and accidentally moved my fingers, so now I can’t see the screen. So I can’t get to the settings to adjust the brightness. My screen sharing is apparently off because I can’t remote access through my iPhone. I’ve tried keyboard shortcuts including shutdown, restart, Command R, but I can’t see anything come up. I tried a different apple support, no help. All websites tell me to go to the computer and I can’t, or to use brightness controls, which I don’t have. I don’t have an HDMI port. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can use a Thunderbolt/DisplayPort  to HDMI adapter to connect to an external monitor.  What vintage MacBook Pro do you have?  Also, can you remote login (SSH) to your Mac?

Comment: I tried remote login but the sites say it has to be set up on the computer first and apparently it’s not. I’ll look into the adapter!

Comment: Unrelated question but same temporary fix - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458395/macbook-pro-2012-black-screen-after-flat-battery [just to link them in the sidebar]

Answer (score 1):

Shine a torch/flashlight onto the display. Should give you just enough visibility to navigate to the right control panel.

Comment: Or just go in a completely dark room, that works. Even with in a low-lit environment, it works.

Comment: Wouldn't work in the linked case, there was no light at all.

Comment: Even with the brightness at its lowest, I can still see the screen in a low-lit environment. Can't you?

Comment: I couldn't when I had the flat battery issue. It just wasn't lit at all. Never tried it since, it doesn't get used much, it's only for emergencies.