# Chime on power on but All Monitors are black

Tags: display, driver

**The Problem:**

I used my MBP-16 at 7am without any problem. At 9am I turn it back on, I hear the chime, but the screen is black. Plugging external monitor gets detected (gets the monitor out of sleep and showing an HDMI connection) but monitors also stay black.

**Resolution Attempts:**

Those I could do without a screen from [here](https://www.creativebloq.com/how-to/fix-black-screen-on-macbook-pro), like all the `hold-these-buttons-resets`.

It is not just the laptop physical display as external monitors are also black. Graphic drivers? I updated the OS the day before all this happenned.

Comment: Shine a torch [flashlight] on the screen & see if you can see anything. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/458395/85275

Comment: Is this the 2019 model? This is likely to be a hardware problem -- if it were a bug in the graphics drivers, then there would be countless reports all over the internet. Take it to an Apple Store for an assessment.

Comment: @benwiggy 2021 Apple Silicon Model.

Comment: @Tetsujin Let me put a hand on a flashlight and report back... :)

Comment: @Tetsujin best I had was Cell Phone flash light but no matter how hard I looked, saw nothing.

Comment: Ah, OK. It was worth a shot.  It might be a hardware fault then.

Comment: did you try the apple hardware test

Comment: @Ruskes, there is no screen. I cannot follow this procedure.

Comment: Start in SAFE mode